# Laravel SUBSTRING on Eloquent query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3, eloquent

**Question**

How do I put a limit on one of the rows in an Eloquent result?

**Scenario**

I need to retrieve only around 100 characters from one of the fields in my result. Currently I'm using a join statement so multiple results are being returned. I basically need only the first 100 characters from `post.content`

**Code**

```
public function getAll()
    {
        return Post::select('posts.id', 'posts.title', 'posts.content', 'posts.views', 'posts.comments', 'posts.tags', 'posts.date_created', 'users.image_url', 'users.username', 'users.toxick')
                    ->join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->get();
    }
```

I'm not sure how to go about putting a filter on the query to only return 100 characters. I've looked around briefly but I've not found anything useful, not to my specific scenario at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant test this at the moment (sorry) but what about:

```php
public function getAll(){
    $query = Post::select('posts.id', 'posts.title', 'posts.content','posts.views', 'posts.comments', 'posts.tags', 'posts.date_created', 'users.image_url', 'users.username', 'users.toxick')
                ->join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->get();

    foreach($query as $entries){
        $entries->content = substr($entries->content, 1, 100);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that input ill be sure to give it a go and let you know!